# Can you help me understand this sorting part in C

Tags: c, sorting

I am doing this beginner question on sorting and i need to understand this piece of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

//this part is clear

```
int main(void) 
{
    int n;
    long int i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int x[1000001]={0};
    while(n--)
    {
        scanf("%ld", &i);
        ++x[i];
    }
```

//From here I need to understand

```
i = 0;
    while(i<1000000)
    {
            while(x[i]>0)
            {
                printf("%ld\n", i);
                --x[i];
            }

       ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: don't declare huge arrays on stack like this `int x[1000001]={0};`

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and more about [the C programming language](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Consider using some Linux distribution (e.g. [Debian](http://debian.org/)... or [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) ... ) with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [GDB](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Comment: Ok i would take care next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is called counting sort. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zuGmKfUt7s) is a good video explaining the algorithm.

In this answer, I'll give a brief overview.

```
int input[7] = {1, 4, 1, 2, 7, 5, 2} // input array
```

**Step 1:** Initialize an array filled with zeros. Here, for simplicity, we are using an input array where all elements are smaller than 10, so we will use an array of size 10.

```
int count[10] = {0}; // array with 10 zeroes
```

Your code uses an array of length 100000.

**Step 2** Count the number of times each digit appears in the array. For example, we will set `input[1]` == 2 because there are 2 instances of 1 in the input array. After this step the array will look like this:

```
int count[10] = {0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}
```

**Step 3** For each entry in count, add the previous entry to it, i.e set `input[i] = input[i] + input[i-1]`. This will result in:

```
int count[10] = {0, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7}
```

**Step 4** Create a sorted array. This can be done in psuedocode like this:

```
int sorted[7] = {0} // the array length is 7 because the input has 7 elements
for i in input:
    index = count[i] // ith entry in count
    sorted[index] = i
    count[i]--
```

An explanation for this step: basically all we're doing is seeing what the ith entry in count is (where i is an element in the input sequence). We call this entry index. Then, we change `sorted[index]` to i.

We do this because, in short, `count[i]` represents how many numbers are less than i. This is why we have to update each entry in count by adding the previous entry's count.

We also do `count[i]--` to make sure that two elements are not assigned to the same index in sorted. For example, if there are two instances of 3 in the input array, we must assign one instance to `count[x]` and the second instance to `count[x-1]`.

Comment: Great explanation Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

It is called counting sort.
Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

EDIT:

`x[i]` holds number of times integer i is seen.

```
i = 0;
while(i<1000000)
{
     while(x[i]>0)
     {
          printf("%ld\n", i);
           --x[i];
     }
     ++i;
}
return 0;
}
```

So, this loop prints the integer `i`, `x[i]` times before moving ahead to integer i+1.

Comment: i = 0;
    while(i<1000000)
    {
            while(x[i]>0)
            {
                printf("%ld\n", i);
                --x[i];
            }

       ++i;
    }
    return 0;

Comment: This loop iam not getting.